# How to display the user Extra fileds in user profile page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using [profile builder](http://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/) free version plug-in, and an [Extra user fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/extra-user-fields/) plug-in, i have added some extra fields to my site, i want to display the extra fields from the front end user profile page, is it possible in word-press ? can some one help me i am new in word-press.

Comment: find the front-end template that is being used to display the user, and manually query the extra user data / custom fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function modify_contact_methods($profile_fields) {

  // Add new fields
  $profile_fields['twitter'] = 'Twitter URL';
  $profile_fields['facebook'] = 'Facebook URL';
  $profile_fields['gplus'] = 'Google+ URL';
  $profile_fields['linkedin'] = 'LinkedIn URL';


  //remove old fields
  unset($profile_fields['google_profile']);
  unset($profile_fields['user_tw']);
  unset($profile_fields['user_fb']);
  return $profile_fields;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods');
// Adding and removing the extra fileds
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
```

I have added these lines in the functions.php, it will add the extra fields in the usermeta table. then i have chnaged codes in the profile builder plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try getting support from the makers:
http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/profile-builder

It's a good idea.

Comment: I have asked the same but no reply

Comment: Can't help you then bud! Sorry!
Do you have team viewer or skype? So I can see the control panel and help out maybe?